# TSQL: How to use variable that could be null or int in a single select

Tags: sql, t-sql

My question is can I do the functions of these two selects in a single statement and get rid of the IF?

```
DECLARE @recID INT;

--Case 1
SET @recID = null;
--Case 2
--SET @recID = 117;

IF @recID is null
BEGIN
    select * from myTable WHERE [myIDcolumn] is null    -- works when recID is null
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select * from myTable WHERE [myIDcolumn] = @recID    -- works when recID is number
END
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How 'bout this:

```
select *
from myTable
WHERE [myIDcolumn] = @recID or (@recID is null and [myIDcolumn] is null)
```

If `@recID` is `null`, the first part will never be true but the second part will be if `[myIDcolumn]` is `null`, which covers the `null` case. If `@recID` is not `null`, the first part will match when appropriate (and the second part will be ignored). So both cases are covered.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap everything in parentheses if you're chaining ANDs on your WHERE.
`(...) WHERE  myIDcolumn2 = TRUE AND ([myIDcolumn] = @recID or (@recID is null and [myIDcolumn] is null))`

Answer (score 2):

You can express the condition a little differently:

- Either both `@recID` and `[myIDcolumn]` must be `null`, or
- `[myIDcolumn]` must be equal to `@recID`

  select *
  from myTable
  WHERE ([myIDcolumn] is null AND @recID is null) OR  [myIDcolumn] = @recID